# Blender 2.8+, How to execute an operator in another window?

Tags: python, scripting, uv, operator

Some operators are global. Some are not. *Transform* for example is bound to the window where it gets executed in. As an example let's say i want to perform the `transform.rotate` from the *UV Editor* in the UV menu of the 3D view?

All I found so far was some advice in the manual regarding execution context. This example maximizes the screen in all open *3D Views*, from: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html

```
# maximize 3d view in all windows
import bpy

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen

    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)
            break
```

But how would `transform.translate` fit in here? I'd like to get a button in *3D View* .

To make it a bit more complicated, I don't only want to `transform` actually, I'd like to add back the old `transform` by `90` degrees back into its location. Which was:

```
layout.operator("transform.rotate", text="Rotate Minus 90").value = math.pi / -2
```

[image]

Do I still would have to write my own operator here? Or is there an easier way meanwhile?

Comment: You can also change the area temporarily: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add or just rotate using low-level functions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28931/31447 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111307/31447

Comment: Thanks brockman. This is what i was looking for. The Change Area.type looks interesting. Will investigate into the possibilities :)

Comment: Hm, no. Seems that i have to create a own class for every operator.

Comment: No need for a class. Select the default cube and run the script from: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28929/rotate-uv-by-specific-angle-e-g-30deg-in-python-script-in-backgroud-mode/28931#28931

Comment: The rotate was just an example. There is much more. It's around half of the operators that needs to run in correct area when i remember right. But thanks for the hint :)

Comment: No problem. But hard to help otherwise, since each operator is different and you'd have to pass specific context members depending on the operator.

Comment: I see. Was worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

The method from brockman. It shows one of the operator buttons. For the other direction simply use bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(val=math.pi/-2)

```
import bpy
import math
​
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    val: bpy.props.FloatProperty()
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    @classmethod
    def description(cls, context, properties):
        return properties.arg
​
    def execute(self, context):
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
                override = bpy.context.copy()
                override['area'] = area
                bpy.ops.transform.rotate(override, value = self.val)
        return {'FINISHED'}
​
​
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
​
​
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
​
​
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
​
    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator(val=math.pi/2)
```

Buttons:

```
    #buttons with separated tooltips. Put it in a menu or a panel
    myvar = layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="Rotate Counter Clockwise").arg = 'Tooltip for Rotate Counter Clockwise'
    myvar.val=math.pi/2

    myvar = layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="Rotate Clockwise").arg = 'Tooltip for Rotate Clockwise'
    myvar.val=math.pi/-2
```

Comment: Just wanted to add, this method has then just one tooltip though for two tools.

Comment: *"Operators can now have a dynamic tooltip that changes based on the context and operator parameters."* -> https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.81/Python_API#Operators

Comment: Ah, that's cool. But how does this work with two buttons then?

Comment: As stated in the release notes: `op = layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname).arg = 'FOO' \ op.val=math.pi/2`, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2516/31447

Comment: Thanks. I don't mean how you pass the argument, but how you distinguish the two operator cases. Sorry if i nag you too much ^^

Comment: I mean you provided a way to pass the tooltip. But how do you  know what tooltip to use? Where is the if?

Comment: Still don't get the question... you can specify that in your layout: `layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="FOO").arg = 'FOO'`, `layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="BAR").arg = 'BAR'`

Comment: Ah, now i get it. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mind updating the script?

Comment: Will do. Let's see if i got it right ^^

Comment: Change is untested. I miss the time at the moment. Will come back to it once tested ...

Answer (score 0):

To have an aswer here for peopel that searches for a solution, I ended in writing my own class. When somebody has a more elegant solution, everything is welcome :)

The classes:

```
class TOOLBAR_MT_image_uv_rotate_clockwise(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Rotate selected UV geometry clockwise by 90 degrees"""
    bl_idname = "image.uv_rotate_clockwise"
    bl_label = "Rotate UV by 90"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
                override = bpy.context.copy()
                override['area'] = area
                bpy.ops.transform.rotate(override, value = math.pi/-2 )
        return {'FINISHED'}

    
class TOOLBAR_MT_image_uv_rotate_counterclockwise(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Rotate selected UV geometry counter clockwise by 90 degrees"""
    bl_idname = "image.uv_rotate_counterclockwise"
    bl_label = "Rotate UV by minus 90"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
                override = bpy.context.copy()
                override['area'] = area
                bpy.ops.transform.rotate(override, value = math.pi/2 )
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

The operators:

```
layout.operator("image.uv_rotate_clockwise", text="Rotate clockwise")
layout.operator("image.uv_rotate_counterclockwise", text="Rotate counter clockwise")
```

The register part:

```
TOOLBAR_MT_image_uv_rotate_clockwise,
TOOLBAR_MT_image_uv_rotate_counterclockwise,
```

Comment: The "more elegant" solution would be adding an operator float property for the rotation, which allows to pass your rotation value, that way you can also get rid of the second class.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: Sure: https://pasteall.org/YUho Consider adding a proper poll method.

Comment: Thanks. Pasteall is nothing permanent, so i will add it as a second answer here. Or you do. Then i will remove mine.